# android listview context menu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I want to put a context menu on a listview.  This seems very simple to do but I am getting some interesting behavior.  The listview has two fields, a textview and an editText.  The long press opens up the menu on the EditText but nowhere else on the listview.
Here are the pieces of code.

```
public class ManageClass extends ListActivity {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.manageclass);

      //Tons of not relevant stuff that I would be happy to provide.
                    pfdata = new PortfolioData(this);
            try {
        Cursor cursor = getClasses();
        showClasses(cursor);

    } finally {
        pfdata.close();
    }
}

  private Cursor getClasses() {

    String sql = "select c._id, c.NAME as NAME , c.percentage as PERCENTAGE "
            + "from asset_classes c;";

    SQLiteDatabase db = pfdata.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    return cursor;

}

private void showClasses(Cursor cursor) {

    adapter = new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.classrow, cursor,
            FROM, TO, t);

    // Log.d("TEST", Integer.toString(adapter.getCount()));

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //I've tried moving this line around but it hasn't made a difference.
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {


      menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "A");
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "B");
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "C");

}
```

Lastly, the layout itself which I admit is overly complicated

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="300px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/TCLabel" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/classtotalpercentage"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50px" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/AddClassLabel"
        android:layout_width="200px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.38"
        android:text="@string/AddClassLabel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addclass_button"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/addclassbutton_label" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10sp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assetclassHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/assetclassHeader"
        android:width="200dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/percentageHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/assetclassHeader"
        android:text="@string/percentageHeader"
        android:width="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_list_data" />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I appreciate any advice.  I would like the menu on the textview and not the edittext, if possible.

An update.  I have found that it has something to do with the EditText.  If I change it to a textview or remove it alltogether, then everything works as it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similiar problem with checkboxes and found the issue was caused by the checkbox getting the focus.  I changed the attribue to:
android:focusable="false"

and it now works correctly.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I have already changed my entire approach to this screen, so I can't actually verify that it would take care of what I was seeing.

Comment: i had same problem with HorizontalScrollView in List element; your answer helped me. thank you.